# Symfony 1.4 Query a table in Mysql database without using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I added a new table to a mysql database in a Symfony 1.4 project. I want to use the new table without using Doctrine, but all the examples i see refer to `Doctrine_Manager::connection()` to get the database connection.

Can I possibly get the database connection without `Doctrine_Manager::connection()` ?

I want to also use normal sql statements but i think they would have to be PDO statements.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use doctrine to retrieve the connection, you will have to retrieve info from the `database.yml` and connect yourself to the db using PDO. A waste of time I think. Why don't you want to use Doctrine, at least, the connection?

Comment: I want to avoid having to "rebuild" or touch the model to get the new table to work with doctrine. The website that i'm working on belongs to a company and they have data coming in from mobile devices in real time.

Comment: Be careful, you won't have model form, lazy loading on left join, you won't have object to hydrate, etc, etc ..

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want to use doctrine to retrieve the connection, you will have to retrieve info from the `database.yml` and connect yourself to the db using PDO.

If your `databases.yml` is like this:

```yaml
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1'
      username: dbuser
      password: dbpass
```

You can create a new PDO connection using this snippet:

```
// create the connection
$yml    = sfYaml::load(sfConfig::get('sf_config_dir').'/databases.yml');
$params = $yml['all']['doctrine']['param'];
$dbh    = new PDO($params['dsn'], $params['username'], $params['password']);

// perform your query
$statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```